# How to import bash history with correct time&date from a history output?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history, system-recovery

I have a file with my bash history and want to "import" the commands on a new machine. The file contains a `history` output formatted as `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F%t%T%t"`:

```
$ history > history.txt
```

So the result is:

```
    1  2018-01-01   17:56:36    foo
    2  2018-01-01   18:01:21    bar
    3  2018-01-01   18:02:02    buz
```

When I replace the `~/.bash_history` with the content of this file, the counter and the date&time become part of the command. So the output of the `history` looks then like

```
    1  2018-06-13   18:10:15    1  2018-01-01   17:56:36    foo
    2  2018-06-13   18:10:15    2  2018-01-01   18:01:21    bar
    3  2018-06-13   18:10:15    3  2018-01-01   18:02:02    buz
```

I cleaned up the commands list before importing it. Just opened it in a text editor and replaced "`^[\s]+[0-9]+[\s]+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[\s]+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[\s]+`" by an empty string. Looks better. But then I lose the information about the date&time of the commands:

```
    1  2018-06-13   18:10:15    foo
    2  2018-06-13   18:10:15    bar
    3  2018-06-13   18:10:15    buz
```

**How to import the history and keep the date&time meta information?**

Comment: Why not just `scp .bash_history user@newhost:.bash_history`?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller In my case I didn't have the original `.bash_history` file anymore. So I had to start by an export file. See the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449613/43477).

Comment: Just in case you wanted to @ ping @DopeGhoti instead of me...

Answer (score 1):

The output of `history` is for you to read. Actually If you look into your `~/.bash_history` file, you will find something like

```
#1528908193
history
#1528908354
vim .bash_history 
#1528908359
history
#1528908591
man history
#1528908594
```

So that's how the timestamps are stored.

Same as DopeGhoti, why not scp ?

Answer (score 1):

@Charles Thanks a lot for the [valuable hint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449603/43477)! It leads me to the solution.

In order to manipulate the date&time of the bash history entries, I just have to replace the `~/.bash_history` with a correctly formatted raw file. The correct format for an entry is

```
#TIMESTAMP
command
```

So in my case I needed to make following steps:

(step 0: Export the history into a text file: `history > history.txt`.)

step 1: Open the file in a text editor and clean up the file. The result should be, that every row consist of `date` + `space` `time` + `tab` + `command`. Since in my case the entries were formatted as `%F%t%T%t`, I needed this regex-based replacement:

```
FROM: ^([\s]+[0-9]+[\s]+)([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[\s]+([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[\s]+)
TO: $2 $3
```

step 2: Copy the result to Calc (or Excel). Now we have two columns.

step 3: Convert the values in the date&time column to timestamps:

```
=(A1 - DATEVALUE("1/1/1970"))*86400
```

step 4: Copy the columns with the timestamps and the commands back to the text editor.

step 5: Convert the result to the target format:

```
FROM: ^([0-9]{10})\t
TO: #$1\n
```

step 6: Replace the `~/.bash_history` by the result text file:

```
$ cp history.txt > ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: That's an incredibly roundabout way of _just copying the `.bash_history` that already exists onto the new host_ which was suggested twice.  Why put yourself through this?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Your're right, but In my case I didn't have the original `.bash_history` file anymore. So I had to start by an export file.

Comment: That was not at all clear as in each case you describe starting with exporting the existing history with the `history` command.